# Как правильно применить overflow: hidden?

Tags: html, css

Выполняю свой первый челлендж, и не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы скрыть белые уголки контейнера, которые появляются после применения border-radius к элементу.

Код ниже, он может быть немного кривой, потому что это по сути первый самостоятельный мой код после небольшого курса, но все равно спасибо за помощь!

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1440px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0 32px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 850px;
  column-gap: 0;
  row-gap: 3.2rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 2.4rem 4.8rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.303);
}

.grid--2-cols {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.section-result {
  padding: 9.6rem 9.6rem;
}

.result {
  display: flex;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    hsl(252, 100%, 67%),
    hsl(241, 81%, 54%)
  );
  border-radius: 25px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.header {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 3rem;
  color: hsl(241, 100%, 89%);
}

.number-result {
  display: flex;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    hsla(256, 72%, 46%, 1),
    hsla(241, 72%, 46%, 0)
  );
  padding: 4rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.number76 {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.of100 {
  color: hsl(241, 100%, 89%);
}

.Great {
  padding: 1.2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0 2rem 2rem 3rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: hsl(241, 100%, 89%);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.summary {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.header--2 {
  color: hsl(224, 30%, 27%);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 3rem 3rem 0rem 3rem;
}

.list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1.5rem;

  padding: 2rem 3rem 3rem 3rem;
}

.list-item,
.numbers {
  color: black;
}

.color-red {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: hsl(0, 100%, 67%);
  background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 67%, 0.121);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.color-yellow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: hsl(39, 100%, 56%);
  background-color: hsla(39, 100%, 56%, 0.121);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.color-green {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: hsl(166, 100%, 37%);
  background-color: hsla(166, 100%, 37%, 0.121);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.color-blue {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: hsl(234, 85%, 45%);
  background-color: hsla(234, 85%, 45%, 0.121);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.numbers-second {
  color: #999;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: aliceblue;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    hsl(252, 100%, 67%),
    hsl(241, 81%, 54%)
  );
  /* margin-bottom: 1rem; */
  align-self: center;
}

.attribution {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}
.attribution a {
  color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section-result">
    <div class="grid grid--2-cols">
      <div class="result">
        <div class="header">Your Result</div>
        <div class="number-result">
          <div class="number76">76</div>
          <div class="of100">of 100</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Great">Great</div>
        <div class="text">
          You scored higher than 65% of
          <p>the people who have taken</p>
          these tests.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="summary">
        <div class="header--2">Summary</div>
        <ul class="list">
          <li class="list-item color-red">
            <img src="assets/images/icon-reaction.svg" />
            Reaction
            <span class="numbers">80 <span class="numbers-second">/ 100</span></span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-item color-yellow">
            <img src="assets/images/icon-memory.svg" />
            Memory
            <span class="numbers">92 <span class="numbers-second">/ 100</span></span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-item color-green">
            <img src="assets/images/icon-verbal.svg" />
            Verbal
            <span class="numbers">61 <span class="numbers-second"> / 100</span></span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-item color-blue">
            <img src="assets/images/icon-visual.svg" />
            Visual
            <span class="numbers">72 <span class="numbers-second">/ 100</span></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button class="button">Continue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Твой `html` показан не полностью. Концовка "отрезана".

Comment: для класса `.grid` добавьте стиль `border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У блока .grid есть box-shadow, он как раз таки и показывает эти уголки. Вариант прописать этому блоку бордер радиус и все поменяется.

```
.grid {
      display: grid;
      width: 850px;
      column-gap: 0;
      row-gap: 3.2rem;
      margin: 0 auto;
      box-shadow: 0 2.4rem 4.8rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.303);
      border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px; <<<-----
    }
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1440px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0 32px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 850px;
  column-gap: 0;
  row-gap: 3.2rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 2.4rem 4.8rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.303);
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
}

.grid--2-cols {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.section-result {
  padding: 9.6rem 9.6rem;
}

.result {
  display: flex;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    hsl(252, 100%, 67%),
    hsl(241, 81%, 54%)
  );
  border-radius: 25px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.header {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 3rem;
  color: hsl(241, 100%, 89%);
}

.number-result {
  display: flex;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    hsla(256, 72%, 46%, 1),
    hsla(241, 72%, 46%, 0)
  );
  padding: 4rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.number76 {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.of100 {
  color: hsl(241, 100%, 89%);
}

.Great {
  padding: 1.2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0 2rem 2rem 3rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: hsl(241, 100%, 89%);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.summary {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.header--2 {
  color: hsl(224, 30%, 27%);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 3rem 3rem 0rem 3rem;
}

.list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1.5rem;

  padding: 2rem 3rem 3rem 3rem;
}

.list-item,
.numbers {
  color: black;
}

.color-red {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: hsl(0, 100%, 67%);
  background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 67%, 0.121);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.color-yellow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: hsl(39, 100%, 56%);
  background-color: hsla(39, 100%, 56%, 0.121);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.color-green {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: hsl(166, 100%, 37%);
  background-color: hsla(166, 100%, 37%, 0.121);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.color-blue {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: hsl(234, 85%, 45%);
  background-color: hsla(234, 85%, 45%, 0.121);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.numbers-second {
  color: #999;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: aliceblue;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    hsl(252, 100%, 67%),
    hsl(241, 81%, 54%)
  );
  /* margin-bottom: 1rem; */
  align-self: center;
}

.attribution {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}
.attribution a {
  color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section-result">
    <div class="grid grid--2-cols">
      <div class="result">
        <div class="header">Your Result</div>
        <div class="number-result">
          <div class="number76">76</div>
          <div class="of100">of 100</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Great">Great</div>
        <div class="text">
          You scored higher than 65% of
          <p>the people who have taken</p>
          these tests.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="summary">
        <div class="header--2">Summary</div>
        <ul class="list">
          <li class="list-item color-red">
            <img src="assets/images/icon-reaction.svg" />
            Reaction
            <span class="numbers">80 <span class="numbers-second">/ 100</span></span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-item color-yellow">
            <img src="assets/images/icon-memory.svg" />
            Memory
            <span class="numbers">92 <span class="numbers-second">/ 100</span></span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-item color-green">
            <img src="assets/images/icon-verbal.svg" />
            Verbal
            <span class="numbers">61 <span class="numbers-second"> / 100</span></span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-item color-blue">
            <img src="assets/images/icon-visual.svg" />
            Visual
            <span class="numbers">72 <span class="numbers-second">/ 100</span></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button class="button">Continue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо!) все оказалось намного проще, чем я думал)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно добавить радиус к материнскому блоку. В данной ситуации это

```
    .grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 850px;
  column-gap: 0;
  row-gap: 3.2rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 2.4rem 4.8rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.303);
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Не забывайте , что вы закругляете только элемент внутри вашего блока. Сам блок остается с углами. Успехов !

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь и совет!